# Duplicate id with another fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml

I have changed something recently that is causing some problems and I am having one hell of a time trying to figure out where I went wrong.  It appears from the Logcat that  I have a duplicate ID, but I'm not exactly sure the best approach to fix it.  I have tried changing the ID and the Class in the XML file neither of which seemed to work.  Here is the Logcat I am getting.

```
06-03 08:55:20.575    3530-3530/com.rcd.mypr E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rcd.mypr, PID: 3530
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rcd.mypr/com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleFragment.onCreateView(WorkoutsArticleFragment.java:42)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4803)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleActivity.onCreate(WorkoutsArticleActivity.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #22: Duplicate id 0x7f07004c, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleFragment
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4808)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleFragment.onCreateView(WorkoutsArticleFragment.java:42)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4803)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleActivity.onCreate(WorkoutsArticleActivity.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is WorkoutsArticleFragment:42

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workouts_article_view, container, false);
```

WorkoutsArticleActivity:70-73

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
WorkoutsArticleFragment workoutsArticleFragment = (WorkoutsArticleFragment) getFragmentManager()
.findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
workoutsArticleFragment.updateArticleView(workoutData);
```

ActivityDetail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_workouts_article_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/darkGray">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleFragment" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/workoutName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:text="Workout Name"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />


            </TableRow>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dip"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@color/white"></LinearLayout>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Name: "
                    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Hero Description"
                    android:id="@+id/heroDescription"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
            </TableRow>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="· · ·"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/dashed_line"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Workout Measurement"
                        android:id="@+id/workoutMeasurement"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Workout Info"
                        android:id="@+id/workoutInfo"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Date Added: "
                    android:id="@+id/dateAdded"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Could someone please lend a suggestion as to how I can get around this?  Again, feel like ive tried swapping the ID of the fragments, and also the classes but i either get a NPE or this error.

Comment: please don´t use two identical IDs. change one of them and clean the project. And instead of class="" , try to use android:name="" for the fragments

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I did what you said but still getting same error.
Binary XML file line #22: Duplicate id 0x7f07004d, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleFragment

I have also changed it to android:name instead of class.

Comment: activity_detail.xml fragment id is now detailsActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the following from the xml file and it worked correctly again.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsArticleFragment" >
```